# VB.NET Generating labels based on files from a directory

Tags: vb.net

I need to generate a few labels depending on the file names of a directory.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use this cmd command in vb to generate a text file containing all file name of a folder

```
   Process.Start("cmd", "/c c: & cd\ & cd windows & dir > filename.txt")
```

then do what u wanna do with the file

**To add labels**

```
  Public sub Form_load
  Textbox1.text(File.ReadAllLines(txt file location that was createdd earlier))

  'add a flow layout panel
   For each line in txtbox1.Lines
   dim lbl as new label
   Flpanel1.controls.add(lbl)
   using i as integer
   lbl.text=txtbox1.lines(i)  
   next
```

This is untested...let me knowow if it works

Comment: oke...so..u want to add labels and then set their nnamss as the file names..right?